# jQuery Ajax Failing to load

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to make an ajax request to a php page. I am using something similiar to the following javascript code:

```
$.ajax("#putItHere", {
    success:"test.php?fish=pope"
});
```

Please not that this works fine with $("#putItHere").load("test.php?fish=pope"). Can anybody give me a clue as to why this isn't working?

Comment: What are you doing ? The success parameter should be a function, not an URL.

Comment: Read the documentation of `$.load()`, it shows the `$.ajax()` call that it's short for.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax are the links @Barmar was looking for. (And actually, the docs for `.load` *don't* show the equivalent `$.ajax` code, although they probably should.)

Comment: `$.ajax` takes a `url` key/value. It is NOT the same syntax as `.load`. Never assume that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
$.ajax("test.php?fish=pope", {
    success: function(result) {
        $("#putItHere").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I can see what I did, I just assumed the syntax was the same silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.php",
    data: { fish: 'pope' },
    success: function(data){
    // do stuff with returned data here
    });
```

I think this is what you want...